# cURL "event not find" error with Salesforce Access_Token

Tags: rest-api

I have an error with this cURL command:

```
curl https://myInstance.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/ -H "Authorization: Bearer 00D1l0000008e75!AQMAQJiLSTqCI5o..O5u3MJ9cDVg8hJJdIUe63mXGN.X..." -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```

It seems to be the "!" character in the Access_Token key who generates this error.

```
-bash: !AQMAQJiLSTqCI5o..O5u3MJ9cDVg8hJJdIUe63mXGN.X...": event not found
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap your authentication header in single quotes, rather than double quotes, to stop Bash from attempting to interpret its content:

```
curl https://myInstance.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00D1l0000008e75!AQMAQJiLSTqCI5o..O5u3MJ9cDVg8hJJdIUe63mXGN.X...' -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"
```

This would also apply if you had, for example, a `$` in your parameter.

From [TLDP](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html):

> Single quotes (' ') operate similarly to double quotes, but do not permit referencing variables, since the special meaning of $ is turned off. Within single quotes, every special character except ' gets interpreted literally.
>
> Encapsulating "!" within double quotes gives an error when used from the command line. This is interpreted as a history command. Within a script, though, this problem does not occur, since the Bash history mechanism is disabled then.

Comment: what bad luck to get a ! or $ in my token

Answer (score -1):

This is a great answer from [TLDP](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html).   My session token also had an ! mark.
Thanks for answering the "!" issue also.

So my Curl is now:
% curl https://myinstance.trailblaze.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/5007R00003SS40jQAD -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00D7R00000482qz!ARIAQJpch8k5DO.D0Ny_93qx2RMU.d1ktGveqQTQulqE_iwpCf1f5au1QQ_dIGFDJscT6Q6k96AM.G53HuriQgZ8v9.B0UIV' -H "X-PrettyPrint:1"